# getFragmentManager().findFragmentById() returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an application regarding location tracking
I've used a MapFragment for keeping the code containing it.
In order to check if appropriate location settings are turned on, I created a location request and checked if its failure is an instance of resolvableApiException.
and appropriately sent resolution result.
Since the fragment cannot receive onActivityResult, I've added that code in main Activity
Here is my code
my Maps Fragment

```
package com.example.mindyourstep;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {
    boolean granted;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    GoogleMap gmap;
    boolean markerpresent = false;
    private OnMapReadyCallback callback = new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            gmap = googleMap;
            gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)));
            if (granted) {
                startLocating();
            }
        }
    };
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    Marker marker;
    Circle circle;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        granted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (!granted) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("create view","view created");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.permissions_say_thanks, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (gmap != null) {
                fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                startLocating();
            }
        }
    }

    public void startLocating() {

        final LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(100)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(request);
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try {
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.i("errer", e.toString() );
            }

        });
        task.addOnSuccessListener(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        if (locationResult != null) {
                            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                                LatLng lng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
//                                if(!markerpresent){
                                    marker = gmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lng));
                                    Log.i("marker","added");
                                    marker.setVisible(true);
                                    circle = gmap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(lng).radius(location.getAccuracy()).strokeWidth(3)
                                    .fillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.maps_fill)).fillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.maps_stroke)));
                                    markerpresent = false;
//                                }
//                                else{
//                                    marker.setPosition(lng);
//                                    circle.setCenter(lng);
//                                    circle.setRadius(location.getAccuracy());
//                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                };
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Log.i("permission","not granted");
                    return;
                }
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(locationCallback != null) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

my Main Activity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String[] autofillhints;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("started","started");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final View view = findViewById(R.id.greetUser);
        final View buttonView = findViewById(R.id.button);
        if (autofillhints!= null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                view.setAutofillHints(autofillhints);
            }
        }
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1000) {
            if (data != null) {
                Log.i("result recieved", data.toString());
            }
            MapsFragment fragment = (MapsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            //always returns null !!
            fragment.startLocating();
        }
    }



}
```

**I would like to know Why the MapsFragment Always returns null
and how to call `startLocating()` from Main Activity**

My activity_main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.mindyourstep.MapsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.55" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greetUser"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Hello User"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/greetUser"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**The following code always returns a null pointer exception if I turn my GPS off**
I've seen some solutions suggesting that I should add my fragment to backstack. But I don't know if that's possible to do in this case
If anyone can help I would highly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong `id` is assigned to the `fragment`.

Replace this

```
MapsFragment fragment = (MapsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

with

```
 MapsFragment fragment = (MapsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```